# Access entity inside twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a request returning something with this structure.

Here is the link of what I have:

[image]

So I want to print some of the mission field, but I don't know how to access it:

Got this

```
<table>
<thead> <!-- En-tête du tableau -->
<tr>
    <th>Vague Id</th>
    <th>Code Vague</th>
    <th>Date Fin Ultime Vague</th>
    <th>Mission Id</th>
    <th>Enqueteur Id</th>
    <th>Mission date rea prev</th>
    <th>Mission nom</th>

</tr>

</thead>
{% for resultat in resultats %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ resultat.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ resultat.codeVague }}</td>
        <td>{{ resultat.date_fin_ultime|date('Y-m-d') }}</td>
        {% for mission in resultat.mission %}
            <td>{{ mission.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ mission.enqueteur_id }}</td>
            <td>{{ mission.date_rea_prev }}</td>
            <td>{{ mission.nom }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

But he doesn't know the field mission because the key is 0. How can I do this ?  Thanks

EDIT: The query I used to get the data:

```
$sql="SELECT v.id,v.codeVague, v.date_fin_ultime,m
          FROM McInvestigatorBundle:Vague v
                    INNER JOIN McInvestigatorBundle:Enquete e WITH e.vague_id = v.id
                    INNER JOIN McInvestigatorBundle:Mission m WITH m.id = e.mission_id
                    INNER JOIN McInvestigatorBundle:Contrat c WITH c.id = m.contrat
                    INNER JOIN McInvestigatorBundle:User u WITH u.enqueteur_id = e.enqueteur_id
                    INNER JOIN McInvestigatorBundle:PointDeVente p WITH p.id = e.pdv_id
          WHERE v.codeVague =".$wave_code."
                    AND e.type_id =".$type_id."
                    AND m.enqueteur_id=".$enq_id."
                    ORDER BY m.date_rea_prev ASC";
```

EDIT 2 : A dump of my resultat

```
array (size=2)
0 => 
   array (size=4)
     'missions' => 
    object(Mc\InvestigatorBundle\Entity\Mission)[404]
      protected 'enqueteur' => 
        object(Proxies\__CG__\Mc\InvestigatorBundle\Entity\Enqueteur)[924]
          ...
      protected 'contrat' => 
        object(Proxies\__CG__\Mc\InvestigatorBundle\Entity\Contrat)[520]
          ...
      private 'enquetes' => 
        object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[524]
          ...
      private 'id' => int 1847050
      protected 'enqueteur_id' => int 100384
      private 'timestamp_msh' => int 550163591
      protected 'is_pack' => boolean true
      private 'date_imposee' => boolean true
      private 'date_rea_prev' => 
        object(DateTime)[55]
          ...
      private 'nom' => string 'INTERMARCHE JUVIGNAC-SUPER-DRIVE' (length=32)
      private 'code' => string 'ITM0022' (length=7)
      private 'statut' => string '' (length=0)
      private 'timestamp_modif' => int 0
      private 'date_min' => 
        object(DateTime)[387]
          ...
      private 'date_max' => 
        object(DateTime)[395]
          ...
      private 'last_modif' => null
      private 'date_realisation' => null
      private 'heure_realisation' => null
      private 'type' => string 'TOURNEE' (length=7)
      private 'statut_etat' => string '' (length=0)
      private 'statut_validate' => string '' (length=0)
      private 'statut_paiement' => string '' (length=0)
      private 'statut_factu' => string '' (length=0)
      private 'check_bo_date' => null
      private 'remuneration' => null
      private 'equiv_nbh' => null
      private 'date_mise_enligne' => null
      private 'frais_type_accord' => int 0
      private 'frais_achats' => null
      private 'frais_divers' => null
      private 'frais_total' => null
      private 'date_envoi_dossier' => null
      private 'pem_code' => null
  'id' => int 152867
  'codeVague' => string 'ITM1702A' (length=8)
  'date_fin_ultime' => 
    object(DateTime)[62]
      public 'date' => string '2017-07-04 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Berlin' (length=13)
```

Comment: How does your entity relation mapping look like?

Comment: What do you mean ? result isn't an entity. It's just an object with 4 field and one of them is an entity Mission with 33 field.

I'm getting the result with an sql querry: added to the previous post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DQL query returns what's called a mixed result and the first convention for  mixed results is **The object fetched in the FROM clause is always positioned with the key ‘0’**.
With that in mind, you should be able to access the mission object this way:

```
{% for resultat in resultats %}
    ...
    {% for mission in resultat.0 %}
        <td>{{ mission.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ mission.enqueteur_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ mission.date_rea_prev }}</td>
        <td>{{ mission.nom }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

More on pure vs mixed results here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#pure-and-mixed-results

Comment: I tried this already...but nothing is printed for mission...just the 3 from vague are printed...

Comment: Did you try print_r() of resultats? Does it return some error or just plain blank?

Comment: I don't know what is print_r ? Actually I have removed my 0 key to get a mission ket doing this `$object = array('missions'=>$missions,
                'id'=>$id,'codeVague'=>$codeVague,
                'date_fin_ultime'=>$date_fin_ultime);
                array_push($listeResultats,$object);`

But still getting the same result...the missions field are not printed

Comment: Ok, try to `{% for resultat in resultats %}{{ dump(resultat) }}{{ dump(resultat.0) }}{% endfor %}`

Comment: Just what i did in my edit for resultats. I got he same thing as on the picture. except the fact that i replaced the 0 by a missions field.

Comment: All of the properties of the Mission object are private/protected, so they're accessible only from the mission class's methods. Does the Mission class have getters for them?

Comment: Hi, I finally get it...i can access the field like this: resultat.mission.nom
So I haven't to use for to print it...evil stuff...